# In factor VAE, do you freeze the discriminator weights during the back propagation step for the FVAE loss?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, autoencoders, generative-models

In factor vae, [Disentangling by Factorising](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.05983.pdf), there are two losses that are minimized. One is the ***VAE loss*** (eq. 2 in the paper) that includes (1) reconstruction loss, (2) KL divergence and (3) Total correlation loss, which is obtained by using a discriminator network which itself is trained via the minimization of the ***Discriminator loss***. Should the discriminator network weights be frozen while performing backpropagation to minimize the ***VAE loss***?

Comment: I had misread your question, I thought you wanted to know if the discriminator was pretrained

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when training the VAE, you should freeze the weights of the discriminator and only update the VAE parameters ($\theta$).

Algorithm 2 provides a nice summary of how to jointly train the two models (take notice that the parameters ($\theta, \psi$) are updated separately).

Comment: Yes, thanks! I noticed that in algorithm 2 as well and had included in a comment, but somehow the comment got deleted by someone.  Thought I'd confirm my understanding here after seeing a couple of github implementations where the freezing was not done.